# pycharm Error running 'remodel': Can't run remote python interpreter: Can't get remote credentials for deployment server Copy of project-level

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using pycharm pro(edu email) 2018.3.5x64 version on my own computer. I configure it to run on the server 172.18.49.158:22

while it connect well and the interpret worked well the error occured:

Error running 'remodel': Can't run remote python interpreter: Can't get remote credentials for deployment server Copy of project-level server 'fpn158'

I used it several month and it worked just well, I don't know what happend to it today.

So I reconfigured it. connect successfull, interpreter seems right, upload successfull and the code seems already in the remote anaconda envs(cause no unknown error)

Actually all my pictures are failed to display on my computer, I don't know if you can get them, let me know
[image]
 ----my interpreter for the project

[image]
-----my configuration for my project.

[image]
---- my successfull upload and error

Answer (score 1):

I delete my configuration about that server,and the interpreter is deleted too. Then I reconfigure them. It went just fine.